Azure DevOps Pipelines XCode 16.0 unable to find utility "actool"
We've just upgraded our Azure Pipelines XCode version from 15.4 to 16.0. We are using the Microsoft Hosted Agent, macOS-14. We have a Pipeline task doing the following:
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_16.0.app
xcode-select -print-path
xcodebuild -version

However, when running the Pipeline we get the error:
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "actool", not a developer tool or in PATH

Was working great with 15.4 but we upgraded because in 15.4 we got MAUI compilation errors such as:
error MT4162: The type 'UIKit.NSAdaptiveImageGlyph' (used as a parameter in UIKit.UITextField.InsertAdaptiveImageGlyph) is not available in iOS 17.5 (it was introduced in iOS 18.0). Please build with a newer iOS SDK (usually done by using the most recent version of Xcode)

Any help what could be wrong?

Hi @Smith5727,  I noticed that in this comment, the issue was solved with sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_16.app/Contents/Developer. Can you please try this command?

I tried this and got past this initial issue. If anyone comes across a subsequent issue about strip exited with code 139, see here https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/19157. Might be a problem if you're using the ArcGIS Maps SDK for MAUI.

I should also add that switching to Xcode_16.app worked. Xcode_16.1 did not. And Xcode_16.1_beta_2.app worked.

Using
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_16.app/Contents/Developer

And reverting to SDK 8.0.402 version in workload install worked

In case anyone else finds themselves here wondering why Xcode 16.0 is not found:
We were setting the path for 16.0 in the path as:
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_16.0.app/Contents/Developer
but for 16.0 the path is just:
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_16.app/Contents/Developer
Notice Xcode_16.app instead of Xcode_16.0.app
We used:
find /Applications/ -name "Xcode*.app" -type d
to check the path.

Thanks for pointing out that we should use Xcode 16 instead of 16.0, solved my issue.

Yeah. This worked a treat. Thanks Jeff.

sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_16.1_beta_2.app
worked for me
https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/10629#issuecomment-2366919103

Hi, yes we have tried this also. Problem is that Apple Store won't allow you to publish builds built with beta versions.

Any new updates with this @Smith5727 ?
